# Iterating through multiple sequential lists in c++

Tags: c++, list, for-loop, auto

I'm trying to simply iterate through a list, made up of two list objects I have. I want to do this without having to create a third list variable object that is the concatenation of the two, and without two separate loops going each through a list respectively.

I'm pretty sure I've done this before, but I can't find how to do it anymore.

This is the code that I am trying but it doesn't work properly, as it takes what I've written as a list of lists. That is not my intention. I'm looking for it to iterate through elements of `list1`, then elements of `list2`. I'm convinced there is a way to format the `{list1, list2}` within the statement so that this is the case.

```
for (auto e : {list1, list2}) { // How can I formulate <<<list1, list2>>> 
                                      //  so that it takes the concatenation of list elements?
    std::cout << e << newLine;
}
```

Looking to have an output like: `list1[0], list1[1], list2[0], list2[1]`.

A simple way to test effectiveness is whether `auto` registers as the "list type" or the "element type". I'm looking for the element type.

Answer (score 3):

Something along these lines perhaps:

```
for (auto& l : {list1, list2}) {
  for (auto& e : l) {
    std::cout << e;
  }
}
```

Comment: If nothing better comes up I'll vote this as the answer.

Comment: The only note to this iteration, that `{list1, list2})` will create the copies of list1 and list2 arrays, so it will be better to iterate through the array of vector pointers:

```
for (auto p : {&list1, &list2}) {
  for (auto& e : *p) {
    std::cout << e;
  }
}
```